# How to force the focus on a modal box on a web page

Tags: javascript, events, focus

**TL;DR;**

Is there a way to force the `focus` to be inside a modal box in a web page ?

Here's the problem: I have a classic web page, containing text, links and forms. When I click one specific link in the page, a modal box appear (something similar to `fancybox` or `jQuery.ui.dialog`). This modal contains also links and form elements. If the user use its `"tab"` key, he can focus every element on the page, elements which are inside the modal, but also elements which are outside it. I would like to force the focus to say inside the modal box, but I can't find a way to do it. I would like to do this in CSS or JavaScript if possible.

I know this is possible, because `jQuery.ui.dialog` can do it using the `modal` option, here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/QjLJk/1/show/. I tried to look at the source code but I'm not figuring how it works precisely. Here's some code I found in the jQuery UI source code which sounds like resolving this issue:

```
this.document.bind( "focusin.dialog", function( event ) {
    if ( !that._allowInteraction( event ) ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".ui-dialog:visible:last .ui-dialog-content")
            .data( widgetFullName )._focusTabbable();
    }
});

_allowInteraction: function( event ) {
    if ( $( event.target ).closest(".ui-dialog").length ) {
        return true;
    }

    // TODO: Remove hack when datepicker implements
    // the .ui-front logic (#8989)
    return !!$( event.target ).closest(".ui-datepicker").length;
},

_focusTabbable: function() {
    // Set focus to the first match:
    // 1. First element inside the dialog matching [autofocus]
    // 2. Tabbable element inside the content element
    // 3. Tabbable element inside the buttonpane
    // 4. The close button
    // 5. The dialog itself
    var hasFocus = this.element.find("[autofocus]");
    if ( !hasFocus.length ) {
        hasFocus = this.element.find(":tabbable");
    }
    if ( !hasFocus.length ) {
        hasFocus = this.uiDialogButtonPane.find(":tabbable");
    }
    if ( !hasFocus.length ) {
        hasFocus = this.uiDialogTitlebarClose.filter(":tabbable");
    }
    if ( !hasFocus.length ) {
        hasFocus = this.uiDialog;
    }
    hasFocus.eq( 0 ).focus();
}


keydown: function( event ) {
    if ( this.options.closeOnEscape && !event.isDefaultPrevented() && event.keyCode &&
            event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.close( event );
        return;
    }

    // prevent tabbing out of dialogs
    if ( event.keyCode !== $.ui.keyCode.TAB ) {
        return;
    }
    var tabbables = this.uiDialog.find(":tabbable"),
        first = tabbables.filter(":first"),
        last  = tabbables.filter(":last");

    if ( ( event.target === last[0] || event.target === this.uiDialog[0] ) && !event.shiftKey ) {
        first.focus( 1 );
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if ( ( event.target === first[0] || event.target === this.uiDialog[0] ) && event.shiftKey ) {
        last.focus( 1 );
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wont get into the coding as you already have the code, I'll explain you the logic behind it.

If your page has the following elements,

element0(tabindex 1) --> element1(tabindex 2) --> element2(tabindex 3)

To prevent focus going out, you basically create a cycle.

When tab key is pressed on element0, it goes to element1 as it would normally go.

But when the tab key is pressed on element2, you need to prevent the browser's default behaviour (by event.preventDefault()) i.e going to an element with a higher tabindex and  give focus to the element0.

Same ways when shift+ tab is pressed on element0, you need to prevent the browser's default behaviour (event.preventDefault()) and manually give focus to element2.

In this way, you create a cycle such that focus never goes outside.